# How to fix the error "You do not have permission. Ask your web site administrator to change your permission on SharePoint Workflow"

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to publish workflow on SharePoint 2013. I created workflow on my local system and trying to publish to live. But it returning a warning popup. I have full control, Design and Read of the SharePoint site. Also I am a primary administrator of SharePoint central admin. This causing issues when I am selecting the below option from workflow:- i) Start Workflow automatically when an item is created ii) Start Workflow automatically when an item is changed

I re-install the workflow and checked the permission as well. enter image description here
[image]
Also after few hours, iis reset, if I ran workflow manually it return me 403 forbiddon error. Can anyone please advise what issues can be there in this? To publish the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to publish the workflow using another account with the correct permission and compare the result.

Please make sure you have "Use Remote Interfaces" permission at web application level:

[image]

Check the ULS log or event log for any clues.

More inforamtion for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/manage-permissions-and-control-access-to-sharepoint-designer-f1c06924-4056-8e53-5b3d-80e40d9cbd56